# Error saving image into Google App Engine/Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blob, jdo

I'm trying to make following JDO entity in GAE/J (I'm using [Gilead](http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/)).

```
package test.domains;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

import net.sf.gilead.pojo.java5.LightEntity;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;


@PersistenceCapable(identityType=IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable="true")
public class Banner extends LightEntity implements Serializable
{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1058354709157710766L;

 // Fields
 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 private Key id;

 @Persistent
 private String name;

 @Persistent
 private String sizeX;

 @Persistent
 private String sizeY;

 @Persistent
 private String description;

 @Persistent
 private Blob img;

 // Getters and Setters
}
```

And encountering following problem:

> [ERROR] Line 40: No source code is
>   available for type
>   com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob;
>   did you forget to inherit a required
>   module?

What can cause this problem? The code compiles fine without Blob object. By the way I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513603/how-to-upload-and-store-an-image-with-google-app-engine-java/1514314#1514314) example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i can tell, it is Gilead that does not have support for `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob`.

The `adapter4appengine-1.0M2.jar` on contains an emulator class for 'com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key'

Answer (score 0):

Are you keeping that file in the client side? That's the only reason I can think GWT is not finding the Blob .class file.

Give it a shot.

Jaime E