# How to store and retrieve images files from datastore of google app engine in Java

Tags: google-app-engine

Do anyone know how to store and retrieve images files from datastore of google app engine in Java. Hope to get a reply soon. Thanks

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513603/how-to-upload-and-store-an-image-with-google-app-engine-java

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Exact details with code are avaialble in 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/java/serving_dynamic_images