# google app engine (java) - storing url images on the datastore

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine, facebook-graph-api, blob

I'm building an application that supposed to store some images from user's Facebook accounts into my datastore for later usage,

All i could find so far is how to upload an image directly from a form:

```
 (form action="(<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        (input type="file" name="myFile">
        (input type="submit" value="Submit">
    (/form>
```

that's not what I'm looking for,
i would like to store images from a known url such as:
www.otherSite.com/imagename.jpg
to my datastore. (i know how to fetch the images from the FB graph api already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think gae has this as a separate service. UrlFetch- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/

Comment: This is for fetching URLs and not for persisting images.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this StackOverflow question which also includes some code examples in Java.

[How to upload and store an image with google app engine (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513603/how-to-upload-and-store-an-image-with-google-app-engine-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can also [directly write file to Blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore).