# How to Create a Blob from Bitmap in Android Activity?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I'm trying to create new MyImage entitly as listed in [How to upload and store an image with google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513603/how-to-upload-and-store-an-image-with-google-app-engine-java).

Now I'm not using any Form. I have Android app that gets Uri from Gallery :

```
m_galleryIntent = new Intent();
m_galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
m_galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

m_profileButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(m_galleryIntent, "Select Picture"),1);      
    }
});
```

And I'm using the Uri to create a Bitmap.
How can I create a Blob In my client from the Bitmap?
And what jars i'll have to add to my android project?

Is this a proper way to use Blob?
My main goal is to save an image uplodaed from an android in the GAE datastore, Am Using this tools properly or ther is better way?
Thatks.

Comment: This is effectively the same question as your other one, [How to stream Bitmap from Android to Google App Engine Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622005/how-to-stream-bitmap-from-android-to-google-app-engine-servlet). Please don't post duplicates.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to convert your `Bitmap` into a `byte[]`and after you can store it in your database as a Blob.

To convert a `Bitmap` into a `byte[]`, you can use this :

```
Bitmap yourBitmap;
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
yourBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
byte[] bArray = bos.toByteArray();
```

I hope it's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code :

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap!=null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
    return null;
}
```

for converting `bitmap` to blob.

### note:

blob is an binary large object.