# using apache commons library while using googleapp engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, apache-commons, apache-commons-fileupload

Is there any way I can use *apachecommons* library while using google appengine as the server ?

I have to add the functionality of file uploading to my web project. I have been doing it using apachecommons.Even if I use the respective jars while in the IDE by just placing them into the `lib` folder,what will happen when I click to deploy the application.The jars won't go with that.

So Is there any way out ?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear...

Comment: @Rick Mangi see the edit

Answer (score 1):

Which apache commons library? http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/? Anything you put in WEB-INF/lib folder in your war directory goes up to appengine.

Assuming you are talking about the apache fileupload jar.. no, it won't work. As the above poster said there is no "file system" to upload to. You have to roll your own upload process to put things in the blobstore.

see this for an example: [How to upload and store an image with google app engine (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513603/how-to-upload-and-store-an-image-with-google-app-engine-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply upload file in GAE. But you can use the Blobstore. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore
Maybe I don't answer to your question about apachecommons, but I hope it'll help you...

Comment: I wanted to know about apachecommons .There will surely be a way to adjust your library files. I mean the files that I have added in the library other than the jars of server's sdk and jdk