# Upload images to Google App Engine

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-app-engine

I am currently hosting the images of my website on Google App Engine.
So, an image on my website will have this kind of url: http://my-website.appspot.com/my-image.jpg

I uploaded those images myself, via Google App Engine Laucher.

Is there a way that a user of the website can upload a file automaticly to Google App Engine for C# or javascript? Via an API?

Thanks,

Vincent

Comment: I hope you will find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513603/how-to-upload-and-store-an-image-with-google-app-engine-java

Comment: appengine isn't really a great place to host images - especially if the are over 1MB in size.  You would be better off just writing them to GCS is all you are going to do is server them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making use of servlet to dynamic upload images to your GAE application.

See [How to upload and store an image with google app engine (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513603/how-to-upload-and-store-an-image-with-google-app-engine-java)

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/java?hl=en#fileforms

Then make use of [C# System.Net Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) to send the relevant content to the servlet for storage.